# How to monitor data usage for each account using 'squid'?

Tags: 12.04, monitoring, squid

Suppose I were to build proxy server using squid with multiple accounts. Is there a way to determine how much data has been consumed by each account?

By data I mean total sum of all bytes which are sent as a result of a request. So if a webpage is requested, the count should include all bytes (images, html, js, flash, movies, etc).

I could not find it in the squid doc. Is there a programming hook I can use? Or another program?

Comment: You can use [SARG](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/sarg.1.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SARG](http://sarg.sourceforge.net/sarg.php):

> Sarg - Squid Analysis Report Generator is a tool that allow you to
>   view "where" your users are going to on the Internet. Sarg provides
>   many informations about Squid users activities: times, bytes, sites,
>   etc...

[Sample reports](http://sarg.sourceforge.net/squid-reports/index.html).

[Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/sarg.1.html).